# itextsharp setting trimbox does not work on first page in my document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've been struggling with this for quite some time! I need to merge various PDF files into one file, and since this is needed for graphical usage after merging, I need to maintain trimbox(es) from the original files.

The problem is that the very first page of my new PDF file does not get the requested trimbox size from the original, but the rest does...?

I am using C# and itextsharp, and my code looks like this (just using a single file, for leaving out any other faults):

```
PdfReader pdfFile = new PdfReader("C:\\temp\\test.pdf");
        int noOfPages = pdfFile.NumberOfPages;
        // Create document with same page size as original
        Document document = new Document(pdfFile.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:\\temp\\out\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        for (int i = 1; i < noOfPages+1; i++)
        {
            //Read trimbox from PDF file
            var masterPage = pdfFile.GetPageN(i);
            var masterPageTrimBox = (PdfArray)masterPage.Get(PdfName.TRIMBOX);
            float lowerLeftX = ((PdfNumber)masterPageTrimBox[0]).FloatValue;
            float lowerLeftY = ((PdfNumber)masterPageTrimBox[1]).FloatValue;
            float upperRightX = ((PdfNumber)masterPageTrimBox[2]).FloatValue;
            float upperRightY = ((PdfNumber)masterPageTrimBox[3]).FloatValue;
            float newPageSizeX = (upperRightX - lowerLeftX) + 17;
            float newPageSizeY = (upperRightY - lowerLeftY) + 17;

            cb.PdfWriter.SetBoxSize("trim", new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY, upperRightX, upperRightY));
            PdfImportedPage page;
            int rotation;

            page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfFile, i);

            document.NewPage();
            rotation = pdfFile.GetPageRotation(i);
            if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
            {
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, pdfFile.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        document.Close();
```

I tried creating a page before the loop, but then it starts setting correct trimbox values from page 3 and on, and if I move the SetBoxSize after document.NewPage, I still get trimbox values from page 2, but then I have the trimbox from the previous page!

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated :)

PS: I already did a *really* dirty test / workaround, reading the trixbox values and adding a page like in the loop, and then the loop gets it correct, but leaving me with a new PDF file containing 1 page too much (which, of course still has an incorrect trimbox), but itextsharp can't delete a page. The suggestions I searched for just recommended creating a new PDF, reading everything from scratch and putting it into a new file, which of course bites it's own tail! I could use something else than itextsharp to delete page 1, but would really like this to work as supposed to :)

Comment: Shouldn't you better use a `PdfStamper` or `PdfCopy` instead of a `PdfWriter` for your task?

Comment: I am just editing an already running solution, and the guy who did this project initially is using `PdfWriter`, but maybe it's time to buy Bruno's book iText in Action to really get under the hood, think PDF files have come to stay :)

Comment: Also look into all the free books he has started publishing...

Comment: Could you provide links to those books?

Comment: They are listed on the [iText PUBLICATIONS AND EXAMPLES](http://itextpdf.com/learn) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `NewPage()` is triggered (either explicitly, or implicitly), a page is initialized and its page boundaries become final. If you could change the page boundaries along the way, during the process of adding content, strange side-effects would occur.

`NewPage()` is triggered implicitly as soon as you add content that no longer fits the page. In this case, a new page is created automatically.

`NewPage()` is also triggered at the very beginning, when you call `document.Open()`. That method defines *and locks* the page boundaries of the first page, including the TrimBox.

If you want to define the TrimBox for the first page, you need to set it *before* `document.Open()`. If you change a page boundary *after* a `document.NewPage()`, it will only become effective after *the next* `document.NewPage()`.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno!

I tried to set the trimbox before `document.Open()`, but that just gives an error at runtime, saying "The document is not open" - could you hint out how to set the trimbox before opening?

Comment: Figured it out after googling SetBoxSize a bit more, and found out that putting `writer.SetBoxSize("trim", new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50,50,500,700));` before opening works like supposed, thank you!